# UserWarning: Parsing '31/12/2015' in DD/MM/YYYY format. Provide format or specify infer_datetime_format=True for consistent parsing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

```
data = pd.read_csv('index.csv')
data_date = pd.to_datetime(data.date, dayfirst=True, infer_datetime_format=True, format="%d/%m/%y")
data.set_index('date', inplace = True)
data = data.asfreq('b')
```

[image]

I expect no warning at all, since `infer_datetime_format=True` is provided as an argument.